# Hidding columns for small devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-bootgrid

I'm using bootstrap 3 and bootgrid to display tables.

Is there a way to hide some columns in small devices ?
I'm using class `hidden-xs` in `th` elements, but it still display data (not the columns).

My questions are:

1. How to hide a column for small devices.
2. How to hide the navigation header only for small devices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this solution you need to use Media Queries
It uses the @media rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true.
like this :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

}

here you can set condition on screen that < 600 px , 
do it for diffrent type of screen.
for you i hope this is the way :

```
  @media (max-width: 500px ) {

    #columnsID {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. Can I use some bootstrap name instead of "500px" ?

Comment: yes you can .as you know usage of media queries is for responsive applications. you can add different java script option and bootstrap option